# Highcharts, column diferentes colores

Tags: javascript, css

Buen día a todos, tengo dos gráficas en una sola, de tipo `Highcharts`, una es tipo línea y column. Y deseo que las barras de tipo column tengan colores diferentes.

Aplico la siguiente propiedad:

```
 series: {
     colorByPoint: true
 }
```

Pero me aplica todo el estilo a las dos gráficas, pueden guiarme sobre como podría aplicarlo unicamente a mi gráfica tipo column?, Adjunto mi código:

```
    function LineChart(Series, fecha) {

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: fecha,
            labels: {
                rotation: -80,
            },
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                //text: '% Accepted',
                text: '',
                rotation : -90,
            }
        },
        credits :
        {
            enabled : false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        color: '#000000'
                    }
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            },
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    rotation: 0,
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
                        fontSize: '11px',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        series: Series,
    });
```

Series lo genero en mi programación para la gráfica.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner todo tu código donde defines el gráfico?

Comment: Lo acabo de agregar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes preguntar antes, de que tipo es tu barra. Dependiendo del resultado, se lo aplicas a una variable.
Es decir:

```
var esBarra = false;
if(*preguntar si es tipo barra*){
  esBarra = true;
}
```

Y después esa misma variable se lo asignas al grafico:

```
series: {
  colorByPoint: esBarra
}
```